# Vuetify fade in transition on scroll

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add a fade-in effect when scrolling the page for the first time.

I tried using `<v-scroll-x-transition appear>`, but it seems to have no effect. The elements fade in the default way, not from the right as that custom transition should work.

The intention is to have them appear using those transitions that are provided in Vuetify, or maybe custom ones.

Here is the codepen with the example:
https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/PozepBw

Answer (score 0):

`<v-scroll-x-transition>` doesn't actually affect the transition of `<v-img>`. Instead, set [`<v-img>`'s `transition` prop](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-img/#props) to `slide-x-transition`:

```html
<!-- BEFORE -->
<v-scroll-x-transition appear>
  <v-img .../>
</v-scroll-x-transition>

<!-- AFTER -->
<v-img transition="slide-x-transition" .../>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOMzzbq)

Comment: But the transition looks like it happens when the site load for every v-img at the same time not when scrolling down. So by the time I can see the bottom image it already have transitioned and just loads.

Comment: @Alex Updated answer to use `<v-img>.transition="slide-x-transition"` instead of `<v-scroll-x-transition>` (which has no effect on `<v-img>`'s transition).